# How to check if a string contains an other string (substring) in robot framework?

Tags: string, robotframework

How to check if a string contains an other string in robot framework?

Something like

```
${bool} | String Contains | Hello World | World
```

[Get Substring](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Get%20Substring) doesn't help, because it needs a start index.

Comment: This question does not conform to the basic minimum standard we uphold where we request those that ask question to create a [mcve] or at the very least inform what has already been tried.

Comment: i have updated the question, it is hard to describe such a general, simple issue with this criteria

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
${source}=    Set Variable    this is a string

# ${contains} will be True if "is a" is a part of the ${source} value
${contains}=  Evaluate   "is a" in """${source}"""

# will fail if "is a" is not a part of the ${source} value
Should Be True      "is a" in """${source}"""

# using a robotframework keyword from the String library
# it is actually a wrapper of python's "var_a in var_b" - the previous approaches
Should Contain    ${source}    is a

# as last alternative - an approach that will store 
# the result in a boolean, with RF standard keywords
# ${contains} will be True if "is a" is a part of the ${source} value
${contains}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Should Contain    ${source}    is a
```

Hope the example is self-explanatory

Comment: This should be accepted answer

Answer (score 6):

i have found an another solution

```
${match} | ${value} | Run Keyword And Ignore Error | Should Contain | full string    | substring
${RETURNVALUE} | Set Variable If | '${match}' == 'PASS' | ${True} | ${False}
```

Answer (score 4):

From the String library use, `Get Lines Containing String`, [doc here](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Get%20Lines%20Containing%20String). Then check the result.

Answer (score 3):

A direct if condition can be used to check if a string is part of another

```
IF  '${var1}' in '${var2}'
    Log   ${var1}
END
```

This works with Robot 5+

Answer (score 0):

**Run Keyword And Continue On Failure**    *Should Contain*    ${string}    ${substring}    String "${string}" does not contain substring "${substring}"    FALSE

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).